# Static objects initialized within class methods in ARC

Tags: objective-c, static, initialization, automatic-ref-counting

I use class initializer to initialize some static variables that I use later in the code.

```
    __strong static NSCharacterSet* _unwantedChars;

@implementation TMGeocoderModel

+(void)initialize{
    NSMutableCharacterSet *_alnum = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","];
    [_alnum formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    _unwantedChars = _alnum;
}

-(id)initWithSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        NSString* temp = [searchString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:_unwantedChars];

    }
    return self;
}
```

When I reach the next line of code

```
NSString* temp = [searchString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:_unwantedChars];
```

`_unwantedChars` is released already.
Everything was working before I switched to ARC mode, but fails in ARC with the following message:
**-[CFCharacterSet characterIsMember:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x11247330**

Is there any way to initialize objects in class methods so they will not be released?

**UPDATE:**
Well it was totally my mistake and the solution was fairly simple.

In **Build Settings** -> **Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting**, Only **DEBUG** configuration was set to YES, while other configurations were set to NO.

Changed all to YES, and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `NSMutableCharacterSet *_alnum` is only in your intialise method. Declare it globally.

Comment: Thanks, @Vignesh. I tried that, without success. The only thing that helps is '_unwantedChars = [_alnum copy];' . But I'm not sure it's the ultimate solution.

Comment: Hi all,I got the same problem and finally i found that the only way to  resolve this is enable ARC and convert code code accordingly.